# How to restart another OS remotely

Tags: ssh

I have a machine that I connect to using ssh. The machine contains 2 OS (Windows & Linux). The machine is running now with Linux. I would like to restart it and boot on Windows instead of Linux.

If I do `sudo shutdown -r`, Linux will reboot but not Windows.

Comment: You have to change the configuration of your bootloader and put Windows on the first place.

Comment: can I do that remotely using Linux?

Comment: You should be able to do that, if you have root access. But I don't know which bootloader you use or what setup do you have.

Answer (score 1):

You need a KVM console access not ssh to be able to do that. Only this way you will be able to see the grub and be able to choose which system to run. Eventually you can change in /etc/default/grub which system should run first. But then the problem will be that if you will change to Windows, you will not be able to run Linux.